# Modifying to make script crossfade instead of fade out & then fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script is set to fade out, and then fade in the next banner set.  I would like to find out how to modify this to be a crossfade so the next banner set fades in on top of the existing one, and then it disappears.  It would just look a lot cleaner.

I've seen a bunch of scripts for crossfade; however, because this script fades "children" elements, not sure how to modify them to make this work.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know,

```
$(function () {

    /* SET PARAMETERS */
    var change_img_time     = 9000; 
    var transition_speed    = 1000;

    var simple_slideshow    = $("#graphic_1"),
        listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('.banner'),
        listLen             = listItems.length,
        i                   = 0,

        changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);



            });

        };

    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);


});
```

html/php (Just so y'all can see how the data looks)

```
$rotban1 = $db1->query("SELECT background_image, background_image_alt, foreground_image, foreground_image_alt, text FROM banner") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1con));
$slidecount == 0;
    if ($rotban1->num_rows > 0) {
while ($slide = $rotban1->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '<div class="banner">';
echo '<img class="background_image" alt="'. $slide['background_image_alt'] .'" src="'. $slide['background_image'] .'">';
    echo '<img class="foreground_image" alt="'. $slide['foreground_image_alt'] .'" src="'. $slide['foreground_image'] .'">';
    if (!empty( $slide['text'])) { echo '<h1>'. $text .'</h1>'; }
echo '</div>';
}
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the animation?  Call `fadeIn` first and then `fadeOut` in the complete callback for `fadeIn`. That way, you won't have a period of seeing nothing.

Comment: that broke it....the top item faded out and nothing was there....unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You changed `listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {...` to `listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed, function () {...` with the `listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed);` inside the `fadeIn` complete callback?

Comment: I swapped the words fadeIn and fadeOut....was I needing to change something else?  I'm not the best at javascript

Comment: Take a look at my answer. The index (`i`) code has to be moved around a little.

Comment: See my updated answer for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `fadeIn` after `fadeOut` finishes.

Try calling them both at the same time, to do that don't use callback function:

```
changeList = function () {
    listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed);
    i += 1;
    if (i === listLen) {
        i = 0;
    }
    listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
};
```

This way, `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` animations start at the same time (ignore miliseconds)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling one effect when the first one finishes, use the **[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)** method **with the `queue` option set to `false`** and run them both at the same time.

```
changeList = function () {

  listItems.eq(i).animate(
    { opacity:0 }, 
    {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
  });

  i += 1;
  if (i === listLen) {
    i = 0;
  }

  listItems.eq(i).animate(
    { opacity:1 }, 
    {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
  });

};
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$("#red").animate({
      opacity:0
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
});

$("#blue").animate({
      opacity:1
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 3000
});
```

```css
div { width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; top:0; }
#red { background:red; }
#blue { background:blue; opacity:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red">

</div>
<div id="blue">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` `transition` and `opacity`, `position:absolute`, `setTimeout()` and `.eq()` to "crossfade" elements `opacity` rendering

```js
function crossFade(n) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div img").eq(n).css("opacity", 0);
    $("div img").eq(n).prev("img").css("opacity", 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (--n > 0) {
        crossFade(n)
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("div img").css("opacity", 0).eq(len)
            .css("opacity", 1);
          setTimeout(function() {
            crossFade(len)
          }, 1500)
        }, 1500)
      }
    }, 1500)
  }, 1500)
}

const len = $("div img").length - 1;

crossFade(len);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
}

div img {
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}

div img:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats" alt="">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature" alt="">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports" alt="">
</div>
```